# Gstreamer video LiveStreaming is hanging when using resolution 704*576 and 25 FPS

Tags: gstreamer

It will be great help if someone help me out to fix `Livestreaming` hanging problem. My pipeline design is like that:

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=704,height=576, framerate=25/1' ! tee name=liveTee ! queue ! mfw_isink liveTee. ! queue ! videorate ! vpuenc ! avimux ! filesink location=/home/RecordingFile.avi
```

It is working properly for single camera `Live Streaming` but if we add more two camera live streaming and recording on different thread then `liveStreaming` will start hanging.

Kindly give me solution to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another tee - encoder problem.. there is problem with tee that it does not redistribute latency event or something resulting in queue hanging.. you can use [bigger queue sizes](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Pipeline-Freezes-When-Adding-In-Tee-With-x264enc-td4301890.html) its about x264enc but the principle is the same - set queue to unlimited buffers (or some big value - but this is just fine tuning)

Try to experiment with the values and write back if not working - maybe there is different problem with vpuenc.

```
gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=704,height=576, framerate=25/1' ! tee name=liveTee ! queue name=mfw_queue max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 ! mfw_isink liveTee. ! queue name=vpuenc_queue ! videorate ! vpuenc ! avimux ! filesink location=/home/RecordingFile.avi
```

I set bigger queue on opposite side of vpuenc as the problem that happens is that vpuenc buffers a lot of data which causes to symmetrically buffer data at the other branch of tee which causes the queue to block.

If you can check if this is indeed the cause of your problem try debugging with:

```
GST_DEBUG=queue_dataflow:5,3 your ! pipe ! etc
```

and look which queue was blocked and when..  do not forget to give queues names so you can track which one was blocked..

Also you can experimentally use leaky attribute for queue like

```
! queue leaky=2 ! ...
```

or maybe leaky=1 will do the trick (try that on queue which is on mfw_isink branch of tee)

Comment: Thanks oyopolsky, I tried solution provided by you for 3 camera live streaming and recording but it is not working there is delay in capturing moments of live streaming. 1st cam have 2 sec delay, 2nd cam have 1 sec delay and 3rd cam working properly.

Comment: @AbhilashDharpure ok but does it still hang? hm maybe I do not understand your original question.. do I get it right that you are adding more tee branches - that is more outputs? and you are than streaming somewhere right? but you always have only one source - that is one /dev/video2 ?

Comment: @oyopolsky now live streaming is not hanging but delay in capturing moments. I have 3 different source for different camera i.e. /dev/video2, /dev/video3, /dev/video3.

Comment: One more thing I would like to tell you, if I use " videorate drop-only =true " in my pipeline then Live streaming working properly but record file is playing very fast.

Comment: @AbhilashDharpure can you post a pipe with more than one camera input? I cannot imagine how is this working.. why do you need tee then? btw you messed my name :D just a SO hint type @ then ot and hit tab it will auto complete the name for you, and you do not need to type it when writing to my answer, I get notified automatically..

Comment: See below pipeline gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=704,height=576, framerate=25/1' ! tee name=liveTee ! queue name=mfw_queue max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 ! mfw_isink disp-width=300,disp-height=200,axis-left=20,axis-top=50 liveTee. ! queue name=vpuenc_queue ! videorate ! vpuenc ! avimux ! filesink location=/home/RecordingFile2.avi &

Comment: gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video3 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=704,height=576, framerate=25/1' ! tee name=liveTee ! queue name=mfw_queue max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 ! mfw_isink disp-width=300,disp-height=200,axis-left=350,axis-top=50 liveTee. ! queue name=vpuenc_queue ! videorate ! vpuenc ! avimux ! filesink location=/home/RecordingFile3.avi &

Comment: gst-launch v4l2src device=/dev/video4 ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=704,height=576, framerate=25/1' ! tee name=liveTee ! queue name=mfw_queue max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 ! mfw_isink disp-width=300,disp-height=200,axis-left=20,axis-top=300 liveTee. ! queue name=vpuenc_queue ! videorate ! vpuenc ! avimux ! filesink location=/home/RecordingFile4.avi

Comment: @AbhilashDharpure ok but this is not in another thread but rather a new process.. those gst-launches are not connected at all.. you should update your question with these facts.. also please describe what do you mean by "hanging" .. better update the question with all these, you can write a comment that you updated afterwards